# An example of changing a row in JQgrid when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to change content of a row in JQgrid when a button is clicked. so that I can put the content of the cell into an HTML input tag so that the user can edit it and submit a form. i dont want to use the editable feature of the JQ grid because it will need a huge amount of change in my existing code. I am a rookie in J-query and JQgrid so I will need a brief and simple example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

See this example [code](http://jsfiddle.net/HaQwk/). Is it what you what ?

```
$('#grid').jqgrid();
```